# how can I rbind data sets which have sequence name?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a problem with rbind data sets.

For example, data set names are like this:

```
data_1, data_2, data_3,...,data_100
```

data set number is not fixed. Sometimes 100, sometimes 250.

My method is just write every data sets (`a <- rbind(data_1, data_2, ... , data_100`).

I want to make function for use loop but I couldn't make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pattern` argument in `ls` to get the object names that matches the pattern as a string, then we use `mget` to get the values in a `list` and finally `rbind` the `list` elements with `do.call`.

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='data_\\d+'))
do.call(rbind, list)
```

Or we can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lst)
```

Or `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst)
```